Symfony 6 Remember Me not working on mobile browsers while cookie correctly set
I'm using Symfony 6 and followed the instructions giver here to add the remember me function to my webapp.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#security-remember-me-storage
The cookie seems to be properly set with an expiration date that matches.
But when I get out a the lifetime of the php session, I'm getting logged out on mobile browsers but not on laptop.
Here's an extract of security.yaml :
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\SpotifyAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
        remember_me:
            secret: '%kernel.secret%'
            always_remember_me: true
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            signature_properties: ['spotifyUserId']

As you can see I'm using a custom authenticator with the authenticate function given below :
    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $code=$this->htmlSanitizer->sanitize($_GET['code']);

        try{
            $spotifyUserData = $this->spotifyManager->getSpotifyUserDataFromCode($code);
            $spotifyUserId = $spotifyUserData->id;
            // verifying if this user already exists in database

            $spotifyUserAlreadyExists = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SpotifyUser::class)->findSpotifyUserByUserId($spotifyUserId);
            
            $api = $this->spotifyManager->getApi();


                    if(empty($spotifyUserAlreadyExists)) // managing eventual duplicate entry in db if the user is already known
                    {
                        //new User in db so fetching the interesting data from Spotify
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setDisplayUserName($spotifyUserData->display_name);
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setSpotifyUserId($spotifyUserId);
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setProduct($spotifyUserData->product);
                        if(isset($spotifyUserData->images[0]->url) && null !== $spotifyUserData->images[0]->url)
                        {
                            $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setImageUrl($spotifyUserData->images[0]->url);
                        }
                        $this->spotifyManager->save();

                    }
                    else// updating the userData from Spotify server
                    {
                        $accessToken = $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->getAccessToken();
                        $refreshToken = $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->getRefreshToken();
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser = $spotifyUserAlreadyExists[0];
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setDisplayUserName($spotifyUserData->display_name);
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setProduct($spotifyUserData->product);
                        if(isset($spotifyUserData->images[0]->url))
                        {
                            $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setImageUrl($spotifyUserData->images[0]->url);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setImageUrl(null);
                        }
                            $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                        $this->spotifyManager->spotifyUser->setRefreshToken($refreshToken);
                        $this->spotifyManager->save();
                    }
                    return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($spotifyUserId),[new RememberMeBadge()]);

        }
        catch(SpotifyWebApiException $exception)
        {
            // here I have to deal with the refresh/access token being revoked
                //var_dump($exception);
                throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException($exception->getMessage());
            
        }
        
    }



Thank you for your help
Ben
Tried to add signature properties but that is not optional and didn't change anything.
Tried on different web browsers.
Read carefully the instructions for setting up the remember me function.
REad this question but my case is different as I'm using a custom authenticator :
Symfony 6 social login remember me not working
